# netsuite sso landing url redirected to customer login

Tags: single-sign-on, netsuite

I am trying to implement inbound single sign on feature to log-in to NetSuite from an external application.The steps I followed for this are :

1. Created private public keys and send the public key to the NetSuite.
2. Generate token using company id, user id and the current timestamp
3. Constructed the single sign-on URL

When I redirect the URL to browser I got either a redirection to NetSuite customer login or a notice like "System Maintenance Period". What should I do for getting NetSuite single sign-on jsp page?

Thankz in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
If (your URL is well-formed) and 
   (your authorization token has the correct parameters) and
   (your authorization token's timestamp has not expired) and
   (your authorization token is encrypted correctly) and
   (your authorization token is encoded correctly) then

        if (this is the first time mapping the user_id) then
            You will be redirected to a special SSO first-time login page
        else
            You will be redirected to the user account's home page
        endif
else
    You will be redirected to the standard NetSuite login page
endif
```

Please note, the very first mapping for an organization must be mapped to a NetSuite admin account.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you do the "redirection", it is called the mapping. This means you are mapping the SSO login to your standard NetSuite login (email + password). You just need to complete this step and then the next time you do the sso login, you should get directed to your NetSuite landing page/dashboard. If that doesn't happen, then there is something wrong with how SSO was setup.